# Yii changing image height and width in _view template of Listview

Tags: php, html, yii

In my web application I want to change the height and width of uploaded image in index action _view template. I tried this code but it is not working. How should I change my code. Any body help me how should I change my code.

```
<b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('img_name')); ?>:</b>
    <?php echo CHtml::image(Yii::app()->request->baseUrl .'/images/vegetables/'.$data->img_name, array(
    'style' => 'width = 200px; height: 100px')); ?>
```

This is the error I am getting

```
htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
```

How should I proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should go like this

```
 echo CHtml::image(Yii::app()->request->baseUrl .'/images/vegetables/'.$data->img_name , '', array(
'style' => 'width:200px; height: 100px'));
```

first parameter is url, sceond is alt and third is an array of html options

Comment: is it possible to link the image to a controller action   by giving the url of controller action?.Cn you pls help me?

Comment: yes, just put it inside a link: `CHtml::link(CHtml::image);`

Comment: ok ,thks , i created a variable for the image and then passed it to variable link. it worked

Answer (score 0):

**getAttributeLabel('image')); ?>:**
    baseUrl . "/images/" . $data->image, "this is alt tag of image", array('height'=>'150', 'width'=>'150')); ?>

"this is alt tag if image"==> this is reuired to seperate the data before defining height and width